# Unable to build R package in Windows

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to build and reload my R package `markovchain`. It builds well on linux. Also, R CMD CHECK runs without any note error or warning on linux, Now on Windows, I get an error like this:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'markovchain' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/markovchain/libs/x64/markovchain.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

When I perform R CMD CHECK using devtools::check(), I get the same message:

**Note-** Some History about the package. I had recently changed name of an existing function in the package and since then the TRAVIS BUILD on github reports an error. For changing the name I just changed name in the definition, docs and NAMESPACE. Does one have to perform any other task to replace a function with some other function?
Please Help.

Link to Github repo - [link](https://github.com/spedygiorgio/markovchain)